# Mastermind code will not run

Tags: python

I created a Mastermind code and when I attempt to run it on my Mac it just says "logout". If anyone knows why, that would be extremely helpful! Here is the code:

```
def masterMind():  
    number = random.ranint(10000,99999) #the computer chooses 5 random numbers
    userGuess = raw_input("Guess my 5 digit password:") #asking the user to input their guess
    tries = 10 # telling the computer number of tries the user is allowed


    while tries < 0: # 10 attempts is the maximum amount 
        if number != userGuess: # if the computer's password does not equal the user's guess then it equals to one attempt
            tries += 1
            userGuess = input("Guess my 5 digit password:")
        else: #if the user and the computer's answers align 
            print "Win: ", userGuess
    print number
```

Comment: try `while tries >0`. And also keep `tries` decreasing, instead of increasing.

Comment: Note that you use `raw_input` in the first guess, which produces a string that will never compare equal to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tries = 10
while tries < 0:
```

will *never* enter the loop.

You may want to reverse the sense of the comparison, using `>` instead.

You'll also need to *decrement* `tries` within the loop rather than incrementing it.

Comment: No I think he's trying to use the same variable in two senses. maybe defining it first as `MAX_TRIES` and then doing `tries=0` and `while tries < MAX_TRIES` would be more what OP is thinking.

Comment: adsmith, it makes little difference in this case since the control variable isn't used for anything else, such as outputting "guess # N?". Hence 0..10 or 10..0 is much the same.

Comment: agreed, I'm just trying to play mastermind with the OP's design thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

more "pythonic" (2.x) way. fixes answers like "00000", fixes `int` to `str` compair.

```
def masterMind():  
    number = "%05d" % random.randint(0, 99999) #the computer chooses 5 random numbers
    for tries in range(10):
        user_guess = raw_input("Guess my 5 digit password:") #asking the user to input their guess
        if number == user_guess:
            print "Win on the %d try" % (tries + 1)
            break
    print "answer was:", number
```